# VBA code in command button doesn't work on button click

Tags: vba, excel

I'm don't know VBA and I'm only doing this out of necessity so forgive me. I normally just do T-SQL.

I found the following code in a help article to take data from an Excel sheet and output it into a txt file which will be used to run through Scribe. So far;

1. I've placed the Command button on the sheet
2. I've right clicked to View Code
3. I pasted the code from the article into the VBA editor and adapted parts of it for my needs (the file path basically)

When I run the code from the editor it performs perfectly.

When I close the editor and click the button on the sheet it runs but the resulting text file is just the appropriate number of empty strings in the text file. It's like it can see the number of rows that have data but not the actual data in the cells.

Have I missed something obvious? I can't see anything more in the help article (which isn't really written for complete novices I have to say) that would solve the problem!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set rng = Worksheets("Discount Template").Range("B3")

FilePath = "\\SERVER2012\IT Dept\AccessSupplyChain\Product Discount Uploads\" & rng.Value & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd hhmmss") & ".txt"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 1 To LastCol

        If j = LastCol Then
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)

        Else

        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","

    End If

Next j

Print #2, CellData
CellData = ""

Next i

Close #2
MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your button on the same sheet as the data? Your code uses `ActiveSheet` to find the `LastCol` etc. but then references `"Discount Template"` thereafter. If the button isn't on the same sheet as the data, it won't see the data using this method.

Comment: put a breakpoint in the `Sub CommandButton1_Click()` see if it's being called

Comment: The code `Set rng = Worksheets("Discount Template").Range("B3")` as far as I can make out is only being used to get the customer reference number from the first sheet which is called "Discount Template." That variable isn't then being used in any other part of the script because that was something I took from another solution. The rng variable isn't part of the help article my question mentioned. I've commented that line of code out and remove it's use from the file path but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: I toggled the breakpoint on at the `Sub CommandButton1_Click()` point of the script, which is the very beginning? When I click the button it just jumps into the editor and that row of code at the top is highlighted.

Comment: Based on the definition of down-voting a question I'd appreciate it if the user who did so could explain themselves. If I don't use VBA at all and don't understand it properly but have asked for help by explaining my steps and showing all the code, what more do you want? I don't think you understand the concept of someone not understanding the code they're working with if you can't understand what I've asked.

Answer (score 1):

To get your value of the cells you are using `ActiveCell(i, j).Value` but in your code i can´t find you updating the `ActiveCell`.

So you are using the same cell over and over again.

Instead you should write: `Worksheets("youeSheetName").Cell(i, j).Value`

also you should change the `ActiveSheet` you use to get you `LastRow` and `LastCol` to `Worksheets("youeSheetName")`

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've altered those parts of code accordingly but when running a message pops up saying "Sub or Function not defined" and it highlights the first occurrence of "Worksheet." I'm guessing I need to add in something with the other variables at the top to make it recognise the worksheet function? (This is how little I know about vba >_< )

Comment: @SteveClarke-Keating oh it actually should be `Worksheets` whith an s at the end, sorry about that. I also corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is the use of `ActiveCell` which is not *obliged* to be A1 cell!

so you want to change `ActiveCell(i, j)` with `Cells(i, j)`

but I also propose you the following refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set rng = Worksheets("Discount Template").Range("B3")

    FilePath = "\\SERVER2012\IT Dept\AccessSupplyChain\Product Discount Uploads\" & rng.Value & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd hhmmss") & ".txt"

    Open FilePath For Output As #2
    With UsedRange '<--| reference active sheet used range
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count '<--| loop through its rows
            Print #2, Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(iRow))), ",") '<--| print the whole current row in one shot 
        Next
    End With
    Close #2
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```